# postgres postgresql.conf parameter listen_addresses required restart

Tags: postgresql-8.4

i need to update listen_addresses in postgres.conf file and want to avoid restart of postgres server process. I tried pg_ctl reload but its not working. Postgres documentation for this parameter says "This parameter can only be set at server start."

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES

It there any possible way to avoid the restart?

Answer (score 1):

> It there any possible way to avoid the restart?

No. That's why the documentation says it may only be set at restart.

If you can't afford the downtime for a simple database restart then you almost certainly need to have a connection pooling and failover system in place anyway. Start planning that so you can introduce it at the same time.

Also, 8.4 is old. If you're restarting a busy system anyway, consider planning an upgrade into the mix. Look at `pg_upgrade`.